# Computationally approximating PI

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm

Is this an efficient way to compute the value of Pi, where the limit of `j` \$\propto\$ accuracy?

```
PI = 0;

for (var j = 1; j < 100; j+=2) PI += (4/j)*((j+1)%4?1:-1);
```

The formula I used to write this is:

$$\pi \equiv \frac{4}{1}-\frac{4}{3}+\frac{4}{5}-\frac{4}{7}+\cdots$$

Comment: Could you please add a description of the mathematics behind your algorithm? That should help us to understand the merits of your approach, over, say something from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80)

Comment: I've edited the question, adding the formula used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work eventually, but this series converges very very slowly.  In fact, as you can read on [Wolfram's web site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html):

> ... this sum converges so slowly that 300 terms are not sufficient to calculate pi correctly to two decimal places!

Here's a better way to do it which implements this function:

$$ \pi = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4(-1)^k}{2k+1} \bigg(\frac{1}{2^{2k+1}} + \frac{1}{3^{2k+1}}\bigg)$$

```js
(function(){
  PI=0; 
  n=-4;
  for(k=0;k<100;k++) {
    z = 2*k+1;
    n *= -1;
    PI += n/z*(Math.pow(2, -z) + Math.pow(3, -z));
  }
  console.log(PI);
})();
```

Comment: I know this is code-review, but is that equation the fastest converging one, or are the limitless / ever-accurate equations.

Comment: There are equations that converge faster, but I chose this one that was close in computational complexity to the one you originally used.  See [Approximations of Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80) on Wikipedia.